# Searching for all zipcodes within n radius

Tags: java, mongodb, geolocation, geo

Im trying find all zip codes within a 25 mile radius from any zip code in the US that I query. I have the latitude and longitude for every zip code. I added 25 miles in degrees to both latitude and longitude to create a 25 mile radius, but I am struggling with searching within that range.

```
    public List<HashMap<String, Object>> query(String zip, String lat, String lon) {
    final List<HashMap<String, Object>> response = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;

    try {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("geoprofile");


        MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = db.getCollection("education");
        FindIterable<Document> iterable = mongoCollection.find(new Document("ZIP", Integer.valueOf(zip)));

        //NEW
        FindIterable<Document> north = mongoCollection.find(new Document("LATITUDE", Integer.valueOf(lat)+ .3623));
        FindIterable<Document> south = mongoCollection.find(new Document("LATITUDE", Integer.valueOf(lat)- .3623));
        FindIterable<Document> west = mongoCollection.find(new Document("LONGITUD", Integer.valueOf(lon) + .4579));
        FindIterable<Document> east = mongoCollection.find(new Document("LONGITUD", Integer.valueOf(lon) - .4579));


        HashMap<String, Object> currentDirection = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            currentDirection.put(north, new_north);
            currentDirection.put(south, new_south);
            currentDirection.put(west, new_west);
            currentDirection.put(east, new_east);

        result.put("new_north", currentDirection);
        result.put("new_south", currentDirection);
        result.put("new_west", currentDirection);
        result.put("new_east", currentDirection);

        //NEW

        for (Document document : iterable) {
            if (Document iterable : result.values()){
            HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            data.putAll(document);  
            response.add(data);

        }

        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        mongoClient.close();
    }

    return response;
```

I have tried using API's but to no avail. How do I search within the 25 miles from the unique lat and long that I use for the zipcode that I search with? Should I consider doing something else or append my code? Any help would be great. thanks!

Comment: P.S
.3623 in degrees is 25 miles latitude
.4579 in degrees is 25 miles longitude

Comment: You might have to use the distance [formulae](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) to get the distance  between them. point is (latitude=>x, longitude=>y)

Comment: What is exactly is the problem? What results are you getting and what results are you expecting?

Comment: I found that about Mongo DB and Geo data: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/ especially the section:Query Operations

MongoDB’s geospatial query operators let you query for:


Inclusion

MongoDB can query for locations contained entirely within a specified polygon. Inclusion queries use the $geoWithin operator.